# jQuery $.get return [Object XML Document] and nothing else

Tags: jquery

Its first time am using jQuery $.get(). Also am new to jQuery. My code is very simple. I just want something to be returned by a .php file. The code is as fol

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <style>
    </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
        var str = $('#mytext').val();
        console.log(str);
        $.get('abc.php', {
            input: str
        }, function(da) {
            $('#mydiv').text(da.toString());
            $('#mytext').attr('value', da);
            console.log(da.toString());
            console.dirxml(da);
        });
    });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="mytext" type="text" /><br/>
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Ajax Get"/>
<div id="mydiv">...</div>

</body>
```

The php file is a simple echo...I have tried many things but nothing work.The problem is that .get does not return anything in the URL ie the url remains the same..As you can see I have also tried to parse the XML file in Fire Bug but I think that is also empty.Plz some help.. thankss..

WHAT I HAVE TRIED

I have tried to change $.get to jQuery.get

I have tried $.post instead of $.get

There is no 301 re-direct since I have copied my file to a new folder and tried to run this 1 file simply.

Am not using codeigniter.. in fact i was but moved this file to seperate directory.

tired to convert the return input into string (as you can see in code)

Also I read all questions on stackoverflow...

copied and tried the example codes from W3C websites and others...

Comment: There is no .get() method in your code, only a post(..)

Comment: I has now.. Can you plz take a look

Comment: Francois Wah.Thanks for pointing that out but isnt the purpose of this website to learn..rather than reputation?

Answer (score 1):

I would try swapping your `.get` into a `.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST", //Personally i prefer using post, you can swap this to get if you want.
    url: "abc.php",
    dataType: "html", //Note the dataType has been changed from default here.
    error: function() {
      //You can do a fallback here
    },
    success: function(data) { //Note the data variable here. This is your returned data
        //I also swapped .attr to .val below
        $("#mytext").val(data);
    }

});
```

If this doesnt work i think your problem might be on the server side. Are you definitely returning something?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot it works.. It return the entire coontent of php file as text. Now am further working on getting processed data from PHP. thanks a lot.

Comment: @BilalTariq No problem mate, if you could accept my answer by clicking the tick to the left i would be most grateful :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok My firend here I found it....

My project was deployed in Codeigniter directory and in order to prevent codeigniter to fiddle with my Ajax requests it took it out of the www directory of WAMP. This resulted in that only the text/html calls were answered and the php calls (which needed server side processing) could not be answered since the file was not in WWW directory...

With me it is always the small stuff.. Thank all